# Change C++ opencv code into java with javacv

Tags: java, c++, opencv, bit-manipulation, javacv

i want to change code from opencv camshift example in C++ to java with JavaCV

here's the part of camshift example code in C++

```
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat image;

bool backprojMode = false;
bool selectObject = false;
int trackObject = 0;
bool showHist = true;
Point origin;
Rect selection;
int vmin = 10, vmax = 256, smin = 30;

static void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
{
    if( selectObject )
    {
        selection.x = MIN(x, origin.x);
        selection.y = MIN(y, origin.y);
        selection.width = std::abs(x - origin.x);
        selection.height = std::abs(y - origin.y);

        selection &= Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows);
    }

    switch( event )
    {
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        origin = Point(x,y);
        selection = Rect(x,y,0,0);
        selectObject = true;
        break;
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        selectObject = false;
        if( selection.width > 0 && selection.height > 0 )
            trackObject = -1;
        break;
    }
}
```

my first problem is in onMouse function. I dont know how to change this code :

```
selection &= Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows);
```

into equivalent java code. i try to do same like C++ code , but it's error in that line.
How to solve it?

Comment: Does the `Rect` class overload operator `&`?  That is the only way I see that code compiling in C++ correctly.

Comment: ^^ yes, it does. (intersection)